# CSS - How to set a permanent position to text regardless to any text message appearing above

Tags: javascript, css, text, css-position, styling

I want to set a position for the text that will be steady/permanent regardless to text that will 'suddenly' appear above it. 
You can see in the two screenshots below the text - "207653577" is moving down when the error message "Number not valid" appears.

[image]

[image]

How can I set the text height position to be permanent in the page ?

Comment: it's the error message that should get the css `position: absolute;`

Comment: You may add `position: absolute` to your lower text box, or you may set a fixed height for the upper text box so that it will always use the same space even when is empty.

Comment: @Kinglish,  Hi how is that working ? I'm tring to understand how the `absolute` property is doing that. Thanks

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form">
  <!-- Your input box -->
  <!-- Your button -->
  <p class="error-message">Error message</p>
</div>
```

You can add below styles for the div

```
.form {
  position: relative;
  // other styles
}
.error-message {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-10px;
  left: 50%; 
  // adjust bottom and left values to position correctly
}
```

Hope this solution will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the position fixed with respect to window use `position: fixed`. If you want to keep it fixed wrt to a another element, say, a `div` make the parent's position as `relative` and set the element's position as `absolute` to which you want to fix.

Comment: I added  `position: absolute`  to the error message style, its working but the error message has moved to the left,  I need to center it back.

Comment: Can you provide the snippet? It depends on a lot of thing. You can just center it with `text-align: center` . If the displys is `flex`, you can use `align-items: center, justify-content:center`

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* the javascript in this area is just for demonstration - you don't need any of this */
/* You just need the css for the error-message */

let er = document.querySelector('.error-message');
er.style.display = 'none';

setTimeout(() => er.style.display = 'block', 1000);
```

```css
.container{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;

}
.error-message {
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f00;
  position: absolute;
}

.number {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<h1> Here is a headline</h1>
<input />
<div class='error-message'>Number not valid</div>

<div class='number'>
  123123123
</div>
</div>
```